# Unable to get lastModifiedBy column in saved entity post saving in DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have created one JPA entity as follows:

**MyEntity** is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "custom-uuid",
      strategy = "generator.CustomUUIDGenerator")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;
```

**AbstractAuditingEntity** is as follows:

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
  public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @CreatedBy
  @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private String createdBy;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

  @LastModifiedBy
  @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
  @JsonIgnore
  private String lastModifiedBy;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
```

Now, I am updating the entity in DB with following statement:

```
MyEntity savedEntity = threatCanvasRepository.save(myEntity);
```

Here, in the `savedEntity` object, `lastModifiedBy` is setting as null.

Even though, while I am fetching the same from DB, I am able to see that lastModifiedBy is set. I cannot understand what I am missing here.

**EDIT**

The weirdest part is, I am getting **createdDate** and lastModifiedDate in the response but not **createdBy** and **lastModifiedBy**.

Comment: Did you configure `AuditingEntityListener` and implement `AuditorAware` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. The weirdest part is, I am getting createddate and lastModifiedDate, but not getting createdBy and lastModifiedBy.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `AuditorAware` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your service is `@Transactional`, then `Repository.save()` actually doesn't save it to DB immediately, it adds it to the current transaction for later processing. `@CreatedDate`, `@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedBy`, and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations are processed when the transaction is actually committing by JPA (I assume Hibernate). So, you need to fetch from another service after committing the current transaction. But usually, you just don't need it. Just believe that they are in DB.

Comment: Yes @Viktar you are absolutely right. Yeah, actually I wanted the fields in the response. But I guess there is no way to get these fields in the same flow.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled JPA Auditing in your application?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaAuditingConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        /*
          if you are using spring security, you can get the currently logged username with following code segment.
          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
         */
        return new UsernameAuditorAware();
    }
}
```

This is required for @LastModifiedBy annotation to work.